# Create PDF Annotations with Quartz (iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, pdf-generation

Did anyone manage to write custom annotations in a existing PDF using Quartz?
I have rendered an PDF using CGPDFDocumentRef etc, works fine now :) 
And i'm successful reading the Annots dict using

```
    if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary, "Annots", &outputArray)) { ....
```

But i can't get my head around, how to write new annotations ..

Hmmm, no-one?? it can't be impossible ... :(

Comment: does adding a comment bump this question? I am also really interested in this.

Comment: @jesuisbonbon did you manage to write annotations to an existing pdf

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-BCIFAFBC

You can use [CGPDFContextSetURLForRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPDFContextSetURLForRect) to add an annotations for an URL.

Comment: cn you explain a little bit please??